# define temporary c++ Eigen variables for convenience

Tags: c++, performance, eigen, eigen3, overhead

I have some Eigen vectors which are concatenated from parts which I want to access. For this I use the block method. However, I need to access the same part over and over in different parts of the function. Therefore, I defined a temporary Eigen vector but I am not sure if this adds too much overhead or is optimized out anyway?

```
auto vec_part = vec.block<NUM_ELEMS,1>(start,0);
```

Any suggestions for an efficient implementation?

Regards Max

Comment: That's not a vector, that is a Block object that references the original vector. So it is not a copy and the compiler can optimize it freely. However, note this chapter about using ```auto``` in the documentation: https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicPitfalls.html Basically, ```auto``` is only really safe to use with Eigen when you don't nest or chain expressions (or you are lucky with their implementation and interface). So your use is okay, but ```vec.block(...).normalized()``` may not be. Use separate ```auto``` variables for that

Comment: If `vec` is a "safe" object (e.g., a plain `Matrix` or `Array`), then `auto vec_part = vec.block<...>()` is safe as well. If `vec` is known at compile-time to be a vector, you can also write `vec.segment<NUM_ELEMS>(start)`, btw. This should not make any difference after compilation, but could be easier to read.